# Unable to view a particular question - bad characters in title?

Tags: bug

When I attempt to view this question: [Is f(n) = O(g(n)), Ө(g(n)), or (g(n))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677241/is-fn-ogn-%D3%A8gn-or-%EF%81%97gn), I receive:

> Bad Request - Invalid URL

Presumably, it's because of the interesting characters in the title.

Is it just me, or is this Stack Overflow's problem?

Removing the slug from the URL just redirects me then still fails.

**Edit:** The question's been fixed, with an explanation from @ruakh:

> U+F057 is a Private Use character, so it doesn't work in Stack Overflow URLs, so your question was unreachable. I've edited your title to replace U+F057 with something_else; you'll probably want to re-edit it to use whatever real character (not Private Use) that you had in mind.

Is this something that can be fixed for next time?

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a dupe to me. This question is "Is this something that can be fixed for next time?", the alleged dupe is "What can I do to view the question?". The answer to the alleged dupe addresses the latter question, but not the former. It seems like not addressing this will only lead to more "dupes"....